# Vue Router with HashBang redirecting to Home Page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am new to vue-router. My router instance looks like this

```
var routes = [
    {
        'path': '/someroute', name: 'somename', 'component': SomeComponent,
    },
    { 'path': '*', redirect: '/' }        
]
var SomeRouter = new window.VueRouter({
    'routes': routes,
    base: 'home#!',
    mode: 'history'
})
SomeRouter.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
    console.log(to, from);
    next();
});
```

I have a /home route in the backend, that serves a HTML page. The Vue app is running on this page.

Whenever I refresh, It always goes to the default route. I try to debug this I found on refresh the full path
of the new route becomes `/#!/someroute`. So it does not match with any of the above routes.

Because of legacy reasons, I am not able to remove `#!`. It will be of great help if someone points out mistakes I have done or suggest some alternate strategy.

Thanks

Comment: why you have vue inside a backend server? a best practice its to divide client and server

Comment: Agreed with you completely. But because of legacy reasons, I can't do that right now. I have a SailsJs Application running that serves both frontend and backend right now.

Comment: ok, from the vue part theres is not way that if you refresh will make that behavior, so check backend/sails router api, that is not a vue problem because your router config is ok, on the other hand whats for this?
var SomeRouter = new window.VueRouter({
    'routes': routes,
    base: 'home#!',
    mode: 'history'
})

Comment: the default vue router config is this
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
routes...